# Parsing from char to digit Prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog, iso-prolog

I have the following:

```
is_digit(X):-char_type(X,digit).
```

When I call it like this:
    is_digit(X).

I get the folloring results:

```
X='0'; 
X='1'; 
... ; 
X='9'
```

I need to get those same results but without the quotes. Excuse me if it is a simple question but I just haven't been able to find a way around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number use atom_number(A,N). i.e.

```
?- char_type(X,digit),atom_number(X,N).
X = '0',
N = 0 ;
X = '1',
N = 1 ;
X = '2',
N = 2 ;
X = '3',
```

Answer (score 2):

```
?- between(0, 9, X).
X = 0 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 5 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 7 ;
X = 8 ;
X = 9.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be portable among ISO Prolog implementations, you need to use `number_chars/2`.
`atom_number/2` exists only in SWI, YAP, Ciao. But `number_chars/2` is supported by those 3 and IF, B, GNU, SICStus, XSB, Jekejeke.

```
?- X = '1', number_chars(N, [X]).
   X = '1', N = 1.
```

Comment: ?- number_chars(2,X). yields X = ['2']. not a great improvement for the OP. Instead the combination of 2 ISO predicates atom_codes/2 and number_codes/2 (i.e. atom_number/2) give better results.

Comment: @chac: OP demanded to convert decimal digits. And as to `atom_number/2`: mentioned 3 systems differ in several cases. So better stick to ISO and insist on conformance.